# Operator cast, GCC and clang: which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
struct S {
    using T = int;
    operator T() { return 42; }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    S::T t = s;
    // Is the following line correct?
    t = s.operator T();
}
```

It compiles with GCC (4.9/5.1/6.1), but it fails to compile with clang (3.8/3.7).
The error returned is:

> error: unknown type name 'T'; did you mean 'S::T'?

Which compiler is right in this case and why?

**Note**

Solving it is a matter of qualifying `T`:

```
t = s.operator S::T();
```

The question is not about how to make it work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe this is clang bug (submitted as [#27807](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27807))

From [[basic.lookup.classref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.classref#7):

> If the *id-expression* is a *conversion-function-id*, its *conversion-type-id* is first looked up in the class of the
>   object expression and the name, if found, is used. Otherwise it is looked up in the context of the entire
>   *postfix-expression*. In each of these lookups, only names that denote types or templates whose specializations
>   are types are considered. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> struct A { };
> namespace N {
>     struct A {
>         void g() { }
>         template <class T> operator T();
>     };
> }
>
> int main() {
>     N::A a;
>     a.operator A(); // calls N::A::operator N::A
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

In `t = s.operator T();`, `T` is first looked up in the class of `S`, which should find your typedef and hence end up calling `operator int()`.

Comment: @Barry Thank you, I was to open a bug for clang yesterday, but I've not been able to find/understand the right section of the reference. Still to learn _how_ to read it correctly... :-(

Comment: @T.C. So, you are saying that's actually a _bug of the language_? :-)

Comment: @skypjack : Was. Both of those DRs' solutions were incorporated into C++11.

Comment: @ildjarn Right, _was_. Wrong term. Thanks.